# Import an .m file

Tags: objective-c, implementation

I have 2 files, `somefile.h` and `somefile.m`. I would like to combine them both into a single .m file (Long story as to why.) But, my AppController uses the somefile for a few of its calls. So, in the top of my AppController, I have an `#import "somefile.h"`. Obviously that .h file is going to be deleted when I combine these files. So, could I just use `#import "somefile.m"` and still have everything work?

Thank you!

Comment: Please, elaborate on why you want one file. It is better to divide-and-conquer than to have a ton of classes in one `.m` file.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Because I'm building the Xcode project through Unity3d. Unity is having an issue with importing the header files, it will only import the .m's. I figured that this could be a simple workaround so that I don't have to go digging into Unity's build script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just made a test and it looks like this is possible.

I was able to import the following `.m` file and use it. But I had to remove it from the **Compile Sources** list first:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

+ (void)staticMethod;
- (void)instanceMethod;

@end


@implementation MyClass

+ (void)staticMethod
{

}
- (void)instanceMethod
{

}

@end
```

However, this is still a bad practice that you should avoid.

Comment: @sch, thanks for the answer, could you elaborate a bit more why is bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, Objective-C works like C or C++, you can only import header files, not implementation files.

Comment: Technically not true. If you are careful, it is safe to import a .m file. If you use exclusively static functions, or remove the .m file from the compilation unit, it is safe to import a .m file.